# Should function name also reflect actions of functions called as callbacks on promise.then()?

Tags: javascript, function, promise, naming-conventions, naming

When choosing a name for the function should we also take into consideration what callbacks set by this function are doing?

The question is a bit tricky, but everything should be straightforward with this example:

```
function problematicName() {
    const elementsCountRequest = new Request(/*...*/);

    fetch(elementsCountRequest)
        .then(getTextFromResponse)
        .then(setElementsCount);
}

function setElementsCount(newCount) {
    // function updates DOM here
}
```

Here we have function `problematicName` which creates request, fetches data from a server and sets callback `setElementsCount`.
How should function `problematicName` be named?

1. `getElementsCount` because what it basically does it gets a count from a server and sets the callback
2. `updateElementCount` because we should also consider what callback (set by `problematicName`) does. So, when we consider all changes made by calling `problematicName` there are also changes made by `setElementsCount`
3. `problematicName` does too many things at once, there is no good name for this function

What name should be chosen? What are the best practices?

Comment: Naming aside, I would certainly do -> `return fetch(.....`

Answer (score 0):

I think [mongodb](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html) has good naming conventions for this case, they got methods like `update` and `find`, and the mixture of both is `findAndUpdate`, so in you case you could name it as `getAndUpdateElementsCount`.